# c struct map to ruby using SWIG

Tags: ruby, swig

Is there any body can confirm the description [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Ruby.html#Ruby_nn17) is true?  My experience is that I can not use `Example::Vector.new` at all.

> C/C++ structs are wrapped as Ruby
>   classes, with accessor methods (i.e.
>   "getters" and "setters") for all of
>   the struct members. For example, this
>   struct declaration:
>
> ```
> struct Vector {
>  double x, y;
> };
> ```
>
> gets wrapped as a Vector class, with
>   Ruby instance methods x, x=, y and y=.
>   These methods can be used to access
>   structure data from Ruby as follows:
>
> ```
> $ irb
> irb(main):001:0> require 'Example'
> true
> irb(main):002:0> f = Example::Vector.new
> #<Example::Vector:0x4020b268>
> irb(main):003:0> f.x = 10
> nil
> irb(main):004:0> f.x
> 10.0
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I should also need add the type definition in the `example.i` file ,just include the `.h` is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can try CStruct:

```
gem install CStruct
```

Learn more on [rubyforge.org](http://cstruct.rubyforge.org/)